# Cannot use instance member 'generateRandomNumbers' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiviewcontroller

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView!
var array = generateRandomNumbers(size: 1000)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    tableView1.delegate = self
    tableView1.dataSource = self
```

//        var array = self.generateRandomNumbers(size: 1000)
//        lazy var array = generateRandomNumbers(size: 1000)

//        print(array)
}

```
func generateRandomNumbers(size: Int) -> [Int] {
    guard size > 0 else {
        return [Int]()
    }
    let result = Array(0..<size).shuffled()
    return result
    
}
```

Comment: i know it's a basic fundamental concept but being very new to programming and IOS development I'm unable to get what really is the error and how to get around it

Comment: i found that lazy keyword is a way around self but how to do it without lazy keyword.

Comment: What is the issue with using `lazy`?

Comment: @DeveshJoshi , as AbhinavMathur write, lazy is what you need : the variable value will be initialised the first time it is needed. That is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking `var array` to receive a "default" value from the function `generateRandomNumbers()`. The "default" value is set during the initialisation of the instance of your view controller, so *before* the instance exists, so *before* the `generateRandomNumbers()` function exists. The compiler doesn't know how to give a value to `array` before the instance has finished being created.

A workaround is to set a dummy default value, then change it during initialisation, like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView!
var array = [Int]()    // This is an empty array, the compiler can create it before the generateRandomNumbers() is available
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    tableView1.delegate = self
    tableView1.dataSource = self
    ...

    array = generateRandomNumbers(size: 1000)     // Now that all variables are initialised, you can change their values
```

Comment: thank you so much both solutions work and now i understand the concept too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the basic answer is the concept of understanding.

`var array = generateRandomNumbers(size: 1000)`

When the code is compiled, it first tries to compile the variables first. So at that time, `self` isn't initiated. So, therefore, it doesn't recognize the method `generateRandomNumbers`. You get the error.

The best possible solution is actually using

`lazy var array = generateRandomNumbers(size: 1000)`

When you use `lazy` it doesn't try to initialize until it is needed. So they are skipped for the first time compilation.

If you don't need lazy simply you have to declare it in the `viewDidLoad()`

```
var array = [Int]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   array = generateRandomNumbers(size: 1000)
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation, i got the fault i was doing. Thank you